# Cannot comment on a thread that I put a bounty on 'cause I lost my rep

Tags: support

I'm trying to comment on an answer to a thread that I put a bounty on. Unfortunately I cannot do this because my rep is below 40. This is annoying because I need to clarify something before the bounty award time runs out!! Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: My answer is a short term fix, but in the longer term you could increase you rep by answering some questions. You answered 1 so far...

Comment: Yes I should make more of an effort. Usually the questions I can answer (easyish pde stuff) are either rare or already answered though but will try harder..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For now (until/unless SE developers remove this loophole), you can use [this trick](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13827/147263) to comment on the *question*. The answer author also commented on the question, so you can ping him there.